# Google Assistant on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need some help with the Google Assistant on Raspberry Pi 3 model B. I have followed a tutorial and done everything right. At the end I tried to start it with:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
```

But then I got:

```
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 434, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/pushtotalk.py", line 332, in main
    flush_size=audio_flush_size
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/audio_helpers.py", line 187, in __init__
    blocksize=int(block_size/2),  # blocksize is in number of frames.
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 1256, in __init__
    **_remove_self(locals()))
  File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 772, in __init__
    'Error opening {0}'.format(self.__class__.__name__))
     File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 
     2563, 
    in _check
    raise PortAudioError(errormsg, err)
    sounddevice.PortAudioError: Error opening RawStream: Invalid sample rate 
        [PaErrorCode -9997]
```

UPDATE:
I now type in:

```
(env) pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
INFO:root:Connecting to embeddedassistant.googleapis.com
WARNING:root:Device config not found: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pi/.config/googlesamples-assistant/device_config.json'
INFO:root:Registering device
ERROR:root:Option --device-model-id required when registering a device instance.
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial, what steps did you take? What is the code?

Comment: hi, this is the tutorial i used: https://www.hackster.io/Salmanfarisvp/googlepi-google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-9f3677 I did the newest version.

Comment: What troubleshooting was done so far? hardware is in order? we have a mic and speaker connected?

Comment: You're getting a port audio error code that's. negative. According to port audio documentation, -->  ` a PaErrorCode (which are always negative) if PortAudio is not initialized or an error is encountered. `

Comment: I have a mic and headphones connected.

Comment: What do i do now?

Comment: It is coming up wirh different errors now

Comment: Makes sure the audio is connected properly :https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/embed/audio ?